# xtend @Externalized example: Error during annotation processing: java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.util.function

Tags: xtend

Has anyone else had this problem? I am using 2.9.1 on Mars. I used the Xtend Example Wizard to create "Xtend Active Annotations". The compiler test passes but the annotation @Externalized in the example client "MyMessages.xtend" is breaking with the following exception:

Error during annotation processing:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.util.function
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:658)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:794)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at i18n.ExternalizedProcessor.doTransform(ExternalizedProcessor.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.xtend.lib.macro.AbstractClassProcessor.doTransform(AbstractClassProcessor.java:42)
```

Comment: I tried the example using Eclipse Mars + Xtend 2.10.0 and it works correctly for me.
I guess there may be a problem with your Eclipse setup.
First try to run Eclipse and compile/run the project using the same JRE/JDK version (preferably Java 8).
This may work because although the example project is created as Java SE6 compliant, for some reason I see Java 8+ compatible references in the generated code (e.g. `ExternalizedProcessor` references `java.util.function.Consumer`)...

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am trying various combinations. When I use JDK/JRE 1.8 and compliance level of 1.8, I start getting
Problem while loading annotation processor: i18n/ExternalizedProcessor : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 MyMessages.xtend /xtend-annotation-examples-client/src/i18n line: 5 /xtend-annotation-examples-client/src/i18n/MyMessages.xtend Xtend Problem.  I will keep trying. Thanks again!

Comment: Got it to work with JDK/JRE 1.7 and compliance level of 1.6